# How to put JavaScript in to the MySQL area?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Is it possible to make script tag in to the database print area? I need to add some JavaScript in to table. How can I add this?

Here is the sample of script

```
 $results = $mysqli->query($query);

if($results) {

    print ' here the Script '






    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#b1').click(function(){
        var data = $('#f1').serialize();  
        $.post( "post.php", data,function(return_data,status){
        $("#display").html(return_data.msg); 
        setTimeout(function() { $("#display").fadeOut('slow'); }, 4000);
        },"json");
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$html = '    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#b1").click(function(){
        var data = $("#f1").serialize();  
        $.post( "post.php", data,function(return_data,status){
        $("#display").html(return_data.msg); 
        setTimeout(function() { $("#display").fadeOut("slow"); }, 4000);
        },"json");
            })
        });
    </script>';

    echo $html;
?>
```